# Using numpy ufuncs vs built-in operators

Tags: python, numpy

I'm curious about the benefits and tradeoffs of using numpy [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) vs. the built-in operators vs. the 'function' versions of the built-in operators.

I'm curious about all ufuncs.  Maybe there are times when some are more useful than others.  However, I'll use `<` for my examples just for simplicity.

There are several ways to 'filter' a numpy array by a single number to get a boolean array.  Each form gives the same results, but is there a preferred time/place to use one over the other?  This example I'm comparing an array against a single number, so all 3 will work.

Consider all examples using the following array:

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(0, 10000)
>>> x
array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999])
```

### '<' operator

```
>>> x < 5000
array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> %timeit x < 5000
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.3 us per loop
```

### operator.lt

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.lt(x, 5000)
array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> %timeit operator.lt(x, 5000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.3 us per loop
```

### numpy.less

```
>>> numpy.less(x, 5000)
array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> %timeit numpy.less(x, 5000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15 us per loop
```

Note that all of them achieve pretty much the equivalent performance and exactly the same results.  I'm guessing that all of these calls actually end up in the same function anyway since `<` and `operator.lt` both map to `__lt__` on a numpy array, which is probably implemented using `numpy.less` or the equivalent?

So, which is more 'idiomatic' and 'preferred'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, thinking of the "readability counts" mantra, the actual operator should always be your preferred choice. Using the `operator` versions has a place, when you can replace `lambda a, b: a < b` with the more compact `operator.lt`, but not much outside of that. And you really shouldn't be using explicit calls to the corresponding ufunc, unless you want to use the `out` parameter to store the calculated values directly in an existing array.

That said, if what you are worried is performance, you should do fair comparisons, because as you say, all your calls are eventually handled by numpy's `less` ufunc.

If your data is already in a numpy array, then you have already shown that they are all performing similarly, so go with the `<` operator for clarity.

What if your data is in a python object, say a list? Well, here are some timings for you to ponder:

```
In [13]: x = range(10**5)

In [19]: %timeit [j < 5000 for j in x]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.32 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.less(x, 5000)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit [operator.lt(j, 5000) for j in x]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop
```

Not sure why `operator.lt` is so slow, but you clearly want to stay away from it. If you want to get a numpy array as output from a Python object input, then this will probably be the fastest:

```
In [22]: %timeit np.fromiter((j < 5000 for j in x), dtype=bool, count=10**5)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.91 ms per loop
```

Note that ufuncs operating on numpy arrays are **much** faster than any of the above:

```
In [24]: y = np.array(x)

In [25]: %timeit y < 5000
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.8 us per loop
```

Comment: Thanks!  In all of your examples is `x` a standard Python list?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the preferred form is `x < 5000` because it is simpler and you are already using a numpy array.

`ufunc`s are meant to allow these operations to be done on any type of data (not only numpy arrays)

```
>>> numpy.less([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8], 5)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8] < 5
False
```

On Python 3, this last comparison will raise an error.

Comment: This makes sense, but the numpy docs seem to disagree with your statement that they are meant for more than numpy arrays: "A universal function (or ufunc for short) is a function that operates on ndarrays in an element-by-element fashion, supporting array broadcasting, type casting, and several other standard features."  I see from your example that it **does** work with a list, but something is conflicting unless I'm reading into the docs meaning too closely.

Comment: Also, I agree that `<` is more appropriate in this scenario.  It just feels more natural.  So, this leads to a somewhat related question, when **should** I use `ufunc`s?

Comment: It is meant for ndarrays, but works with lists and tuples because they are the basic container for Python and most your data may already be using these types. Using ufuncs is more or less like calling `asarray` on your element first.